# The method getContextPath() is undefined

Tags: jsp, servlets

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7wQR.png
The method getContextPath() is undefined for the type ServletContext    reports.jsp line 50 JSP Problem
I can't figure out this problem.
I tried to set build path but didnt help,
I am using tomcat7 windows 8.1 
plzz help

Comment: Next time you get an error, just copypaste it in [a search field](https://google.com/search?q=%22The+method+getContextPath()+is+undefined+for+the+type+ServletContext%22) first.

Answer (score 0):

the ServletContext.getContextPath() is only available from Servlet 2.5 spec.